# First query or connection to AWS RDS is very very slow

Tags: mysql, laravel, amazon-ec2, amazon-rds, database-performance

I have a product built with laravel, with multi-tenancy.
Deployed on EC2 instance and using AWS RDS as the database server.

I am currently having around 100 databases on the production.
Laravel's hyn tenancy module is handling the connections.

Now, the problem is for each tenant after some idle time, the first request takes too long. around 15-20 seconds. and after that, it works smoothly.

In the test environment, we are not using RDS but a local MySQL instance. and the problem does not occur in the test environment. the only difference between test and production is the AWS RDS.

I have looked into max connections, query cache, and so on... but no luck so far.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Is this Aurora or normal RDS?

Comment: its normal RDS @ErmiyaEskandary

Comment: If I recall correctly, RDS has a setting that the DB will go into an "idle" mode and will need to "wake up" after that. That's why a first query will take a while. It's a cost-saving setting, I believe, but it adds that annoyance.

Comment: @PauloHgo any possible solution?

Comment: Ok so found no other solution, so finally, I upgraded the instance, money can solve everything :)

Answer (score 2):

The solution will depend on what kind of RDS you have.
I assume it's serverless (more common). In that case, there's a setting for min and max for ACU. It will (I believe) go down to zero by default if the DB is not accessed in a while. Check that and see if it is properly set.

If you have a Provisioned DB, then it's more complex. It will start caching things once queries are executed but until a particular query is run, you will be waiting for the DB to "wake up" and run a full query.
Check [this page](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/aurora-serverless-v2.setting-capacity.html#aurora-serverless-v2.min_capacity_considerations) for relevant info.

Comment: I am using Amazon RDS and not Amazon Arora